# Should I build my own PyroCMS module...?

Tags: codeigniter, module, pyrocms

I'm using PyroStreams on my PyroCMS-based site, which is working great, but the front-end search functionality it offers is a bit too limiting for my needs.

My stream consists of over 20 fields. On each page of the site I want a simple keyword search box which will search on 3 of the fields in my stream. Currently I'm using the PyroStreams search form for this and it's working great.

But I also want an advanced search page which will build a form based on all 20 fields, pulling in data from the stream to build it, e.g. in my steam I have a field-type of Country and on my advanced search form I want to include a dropdown list containing all the countries found within that field-type.

What I'm asking is what is the best approach to doing this?

Should I build my own module, separate from the PyroStreams module to perform this, or is that a bit of a sledgehammer to crack a nut?

I'm a bit of a novice in this field so all help & advice is greatly appreciated.

Tony.

Comment: I'm not answering because I don't know anything about the platform, but coming from general programming knowledge, I would say that generally writing one's own version of an existing platform or toolkit would be sledgehammering a nut, yes - not to mention, it increases the chances of security risks and/or bugs. But again, I don't know this platform, so I could be completely wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just Grab sample module from here...https://github.com/pyrocms/sample and understand the folder and file structure.. Its quite easy to develop custom module in pyrocms.You just have to provide basic module detail in the detail.php to install the module. then create a new controller with the same name as module in controllers folder and same for the view and model. you can easily understand once you will go through the sample module..

url stucture will be like this

{{ url:site }}controller_name/method_name/paramate of method.

Hopefully this will help you..

Comment: Thanks for your advice @pramod. I've decided to build my own module and have already started on it. Everything is going well, so I'm glad I made the decision I did. Thanks again. Tony.

Answer (score 0):

This is a late answer, but PyroCMS now has a search module.

You can see the documentation to learn how to use it from a developers point of view here:

[PyroCMS 2.2 Search Documentation](http://docs.pyrocms.com/2.2/manual/developers/tools/search)